# Saving text file without closing it

Tags: vba, excel

There is plenty of information regarding how to write to a text-file in VBA, but what I need is to write **and save** without closing the file. I run some time consuming macros, and need to save information from time to time, since the macro tends to crash.

This is what I have right now

```
    sFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & wsRes & ".txt"
    lFile = FreeFile
    Open sFile For Append As lFile
    Print #lFile, "======" //this is where I need to save the file as well.
    Close lFile
```

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid VBA can't do that as-is, apart from using Close and then re-opening it again.  Scripting.FileSystemObject also lacks this functionality.

To have a flush-able file output, you could use the Windows API for writing out your file.  Pointers here are CreateFile & CloseHandle for opening / closing the file, WriteFile for writing to it, and FlushFileBuffers for writing anything that's left in the write buffer.

Comment: Thank you. If I close and open the file again, can I tell VBA to continue writing from a certain row? Maybe the best workaround is to delete the old file and save a new one for each output?

Comment: Sure, VBA's "open" can append to existing files perfectly fine, like you already did.  When writing whole lines, it should start writing at a new line when appending... unless Close doesn't flush the file buffers like it should when it crashes.  You could also test FileSystemObject; it can also append to files when opening; maybe that component does flush properly before a crash?

Comment: It seems like Close should flush, so I guess I'll try that first. If it doesn't, I'll have a look at FileSystemObject.

Thank you for helping!